# HPageBreaks.Location.row, Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is throwing subscript out of range error.

```
x = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Address
```

When `i` is `1` and `2` the code executes fine.. when `i` is `3` in the loop the code throws an error..

```
ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count is 133
```

Can someone please help me solve the issue

Comment: Please create a [reprex] with your loop.

Comment: Does the Active sheet changes during your processing? Try to use a worksheet variable instead of Activesheet

Comment: No sheet is is constant, I have tried worksheets ("sheet1") as well, I am finding same error